# How to get original absolute file path of the class when deployed to server?

Tags: java, file, path, directory, filepath

How to get original absolute file path of the class when deployed to server???

I have two projects (projectA, projectB) both are always located in the same folder "C:/Projects", only one of the project is deployed at a time, and they will get deploy on a different machine, so I need to find the absolute path for files in projectB by using path of projectA.

I can't add dependency between the two as well.

I want to access some files in projectB from projectA by using absolute path of the files in projectA, and I was thinking

```
// Add "/../" to the absolute path to navigate back by one level.
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/../projectB/test.xml"
```

But when I built and deployed projectA on weblogic, the absolute path of the class in projectA points to the weblogic folder, since that is where it got deployed. But I really want the absolute path of where the original source code is located.

```
"C:/Projects/projectA/classes"
```

I tried:

```
projectA.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

And bunches other, they all work on local testing, but failed when deployed to weblogic, and gives me:

```
/C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/
```

Comment: Why not deploying all the classes that you need for each project? It's really a bad practice what you're trying to do. A deployed project cannot depend on its workspace/source files.

Comment: Can't do it, that is the thing

Comment: May I ask why? Seems like something is really awkward about your requirements.

Comment: You'll have to hard code the absolute path, i.e. using a `static final String`.

Comment: @JonnyHenly doesn't work, I already defined as static final

Comment: @SHG that is just how our project is designed, they are meant to run independently from another, but I need that one specific file from project B

Comment: @OuYe I'm not saying to make the string `static final`, I'm saying hard code the path to the project, i.e. `static final String PROJECT_B_PATH = "C:\\path\to\project\b"` and use that wherever you need it. Otherwise you're going to need to write and implement an algorithm to start in the root directory and search in each sub-directory until the path to project B is found.

Comment: @JonnyHenly can't do that, like I say, they will get deploy on another machine, the path will change depending on where the person wants the Projects folder to be

Comment: Then you'll have to bundle project A and project B together and use relative paths. What good is having the *original absolute file path* when they're getting deployed on another machine where the path and OS will change?? Why not have the person tell project A where project B is located?

Comment: @JonnyHenly although the path of the folder will change when deploy, but both projects are always in the same "Project" folder, so having the absolute for one project will be able to navigate backward to another project, but only one of the will get deploy, so my problem is I can't get the path to the project folder, but rather it points to the web logic folder. My mentor doesn't want to add additional dependency between the projects, hence this method